# getline loop disables printing to txt

Tags: c++, string, fstream, ifstream, boolean-expression

My C++ program writes string inputs to a txt file.
I have a bool function check(), which takes the input, and reads the file, returning true if it finds a matching string, and ends by returning false (for the cases when it doesn't return in the if{}).

another function, nuc(), analyzes the result of check() and writes differently based on the results.

I always empty fragments.txt before running the program, so check() always returns false. Here's the pseudocode:

```
if(check()){
cout << "present" << endl;   
...
}
else{
   cout << "not present" << endl;
   fragments.txt << string;
   counts.txt << int;
}
```

if I run to code as above, the program couts "not present" (meaning it calls else{}), writes to the count file, but doesn't write to the txt file.

If i replace if(check()) with if(false), it calls else{} as above, couting "not present" writes to the count file, AND writes to the txt file.

here's the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

ifstream sections("sections.txt");
fstream fragments("fragments.txt");
fstream counts("counts.txt");
string fragment;
streampos fragpos;


bool check(string fragment_p) {
    string fragment_r;
    while (getline(fragments, fragment_r)) {
        if (fragment_p == fragment_r) {
            fragpos = fragments.tellg();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


void nuc(string section, int position) {
    string fragment_f;
    bool present;
    int count;

    try {
        section.at(position + 1);
        nuc(section, position + 1);
    }

    catch (exception out_of_range) {
        fragment_f = shorten(fragment);

        if (check(fragment_f)) {
            cout << "present" << endl;
            counts.seekp(fragpos);
            counts.seekg(fragpos);
            counts >> count;
        }
        else{
            cout << "not present" << endl;
            fragments << fragment_f << "\n";
            counts << 1 << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: adding main() and example txt

sections.txt containing only

```
BAT
```

should result in a fragments.txt:

```
(an empty line)
T
A.
AT
B..
B.T
BA.
BAT
```

And it does, when i replace the check() call with false. I suspect the issue may have something to do with the read/write positions in fragments, as that seems to be the only thing affected by check(), but i really don't know.

main():

```
            int main() {
                string section;
                size_t pos = 0;

                if (!fragments || !counts || !sections)
                {
                    std::cout << "Error opening files!" << endl;
                    return 1;
                }

                while (getline(sections, section)) {

                    nuc(section, pos);
                }

                std::cout << "fragmentation complete" << endl;

                sections.close();
                fragments.close();
                counts.close();
                system("pause");
                return 0;
```

EDIT 2: I noticed that if i disable the getline loop in check() with /**/, or open fragments.txt a second time as fragmentsr as below

```
        ifstream fragmentsr("fragments.txt", ios::app);
```

and call check() (referencing fragmentsr in its getline loop instead of fragments), the program writes as intended, further emphasizing that the getline loop is responsible for the writing issue.

Comment: I recommend providing or hard-coding an input set that exposes your reported error.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm sorry but i'm not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: You should, at the very least, provide a small sections.txt that causes the problem you wish us to help investigate and a `main` to set things up. If we invent our own we may not be able to reproduce the problem, or may produce a different one.

Comment: @user4581301 added example txt and main() to OP

Answer (score 0):

May check() make fragments have eof flag.

Comment: `while (getline(fragments, fragment_r))` includes a test for end of file. If that is not what you are suggesting, I recommend expanding the answer.

Comment: This code will make fstream have eof flag and that's a "badbit", call good() to check it. A stream which have !good() state, it may be not able to read for.